# Django template - for look iterate over variable

Tags: python-3.x, django, jinja2

I am looking for a way to iterate over variable in django template.
In template I do not know how to assign variable in for loop.

In get_context_date of ListView i am assigning data of two files to two vars like:

```
    context[f"{t_name}_header"] = db_oper
    context[f"{t_name}_body"] = db_header
```

Context is generated for two files which results with vars like:

```
    context["test1_header"]
    context["test1_body"]
    context["test2_header"]
    context["test2_body"]`
```

test1 and test2 are names populated from model.
I can access them with object_list in template.

In template html file I would like to iterate over context like:

```
    {% for object in object_list %}
    {% for item in object.name|add:"_header" %} 
    ...do stuff
    {% endfor %}
    {% for item in object.name|add:"_body" %} 
    ...do stuff
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}`
```

In result in html template I got nothing.

How to properly filter variable in for loop so it could go thru eq. test1_header ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can change your data structure? Using a dict for example:

```
context['list'] = {}

for t_name in t_names:
    context['list'][t_name] = {"header": db_oper, "body": db_header}
```

And then in your template:

```
{% for t_name, data in list.items %}
    <h2>{{ t_name }}</h2>
    {% for item in data.header %} 
        ...do stuff
    {% endfor %}
    {% for item in data.body %} 
        ...do stuff
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. That solved my issue. I just had to slightly modify loop in template to: {% for key, data in list.items %}

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you made it work. I'm going to edit my answer to fix it, please consider marking it as the accepted answer